# Error on loading csv file from hdfs using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the code I'm running:

```
scala> val telecom = sqlContext.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///CDR.csv")
```

but I am getting an error:

```
<console>:23: error: not found: value sqlContext
   val telecom = sqlContext.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///CDR.csv")
```

Comment: You haven't defined `sqlContext`. Are you running this in the spark-shell? Which version of spark?

Comment: How to define sqlContext? Yes, am running into spark shell. version 2.1.1

Comment: In version 2.0+ you should use a `SparkSession` instead of `sqlContext`. In the shell, `spark` should be defined which you can use.

Comment: val telecom = sparkSession.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///CDR.csv")  This still gives the error

Comment: `val telecom = spark.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///CDR.csv")`.